# Python Flask - Making Jinja2 template logic-free

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I've just began using Python Flask with Jinja2 (the templating system for those who don't know) and have encountered a roadblock in the templating part..

So, with the concept of logic and templating separation in mind, I'm trying to remove the last thing that I find impossible to remove: for loop iteration.

I'll try to narrow the issue as much as possible.

Basically I have this view which defines the homepage:

```
# front page
def front(): # define front page
    i = db.docs.find() # find docs in db and assign to var "i"
    docs = [k for k in i] # iterate over "i" vals and assign to docs which is then iterable
    return render_template('index.html', docs=docs) # render the "index.html" template and make the "docs" variable available for it
```

Then I have the **index.html** (included just the piece of the question's focus):

```
<title> Localhost - Homepage </title>

<div class=doc>
  {% for doc in docs %} # iterate over every doc in docs
      <h4><a 
              href="/post/{{ doc.slug }}/">{{ doc.title }} # get the **doc slug** and **doc title**
          </a>
      </h4>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The problem is here ^ is there a way to iterate in the view (where all the logic should reside) and have a predefined val to print in the template ( like `<div>{{ docs.title }}</div>` )?

Comment: Looping in templates is **more than fine**; in fact, that's one of the functions that really should reside in template.

Comment: The alternative would be to pre-generate all the `<h4><a href="...">title</a></h4>` text in your view. That's akin to putting the wagon before the horse; you really don't want to do that.

Comment: When people talk about keeping logic out of the template they are talking about *business logic*. Layout can still use conditionals and looping *if it serves to build a layout*.

Comment: This seems fine, you might however replace `[k for k in i]` by `list(i)` which should do the same, and furthermore, I would use `i` conventionally for an item of a list and not for an iterable.

Comment: Reinforcing the comment by Martijn, business logic should reside on the controller layer (called view in Flask), presentation logic in the view layer (the template). Stuffing presentation logic in the controller is silly.

Comment: So, reading your comments it seems that logic in a template is ok if it's about building a layout. Think I'll stick with that then. I don't know if you know Drupal but (when I developed in Php) I never met a loop in any **tpl** file. For example this is what it got to display the content of a page: `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` or its Python equivalent `print render(page['content'])`

Comment: @wirrbel Thanks. Yeah when I code it tends to get a bit messy hehe. Following your advice I changed it to `docs = list(db)`

Comment: @user3535094 the take-away point is "separation of concerns". Business logic that has nothing to do with output-rending should not go into the template, however, your loop is a perfect example of what should go into the template. You do not want to create html in `front`, this is exactly the templates job.

Just look at the code and ask yourself: "Is this readable and maintainable?" -- it is when its written this way.